# Pivot query without [ ]

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have created this view with this pivot query:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ws_monatsreport] AS
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT a.AdressNrADR,k.monat,p.Id_kopf,a.name + ' '+ a.vorname as Name,p.Artikel, p.Tag,CASE WHEN CAST(p.wert  AS VARCHAR(10)) = '' THEN CAST(p.Menge AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE CAST(p.Wert AS VARCHAR(10)) END AS Menge 
    FROM   ( ( ( ZUS_Monatsreport_Kopf k
        LEFT JOIN  ZUS_Monatsreport_Pos p ON k.Id =  p.Id_Kopf)  
        LEFT JOIN  ADR_Adressen a ON k.Adresse =  a.AdressNrADR)  
        LEFT JOIN  ADR_GruppenLink gl ON a.AdressNrADR =  gl.AdressNrADR)  
        LEFT JOIN  ADR_Gruppen g ON gl.GruppeADR =  g.GruppeADR 
)src
pivot
( max(menge)
for tag IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[35])
) piv;

GO
```

Now I have to call this view from our ERP system. In our system I can write SQL queries, but the problem is that `[ ]` is used for calling parameters inside our ERP.

So, if I write

```
SELECT [AdressNrADR],[Monat],[Id_kopf,Name,Artikel],[1],[2] and so on 
FROM ws_monatsreport
```

I get an error.

Is there some way I can do this without using `[]`?

If I take them away I don't get the result I want :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

List your columns explicitly instead of `*` and assign some other names for your `[1], [2], ...` columns in the definition of the view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ws_monatsreport] AS
SELECT
    AdressNrADR
    ,monat
    ,Id_kopf
    ,Name
    ,Artikel
    ,[1] AS Tag1
    ,[2] AS Tag2
    ,[3] AS Tag3
    ...
    ,[35] AS Tag35
FROM
(
    SELECT
        a.AdressNrADR
        ,k.monat
        ,p.Id_kopf
        ,a.name + ' '+ a.vorname as Name
        ,p.Artikel
        ,p.Tag
        ,CASE WHEN CAST(p.wert  AS VARCHAR(10)) = '' 
            THEN CAST(p.Menge AS VARCHAR(10)) 
            ELSE CAST(p.Wert AS VARCHAR(10)) END AS Menge 
    FROM
        ZUS_Monatsreport_Kopf k
        LEFT JOIN ZUS_Monatsreport_Pos p ON k.Id = p.Id_Kopf
        LEFT JOIN ADR_Adressen a ON k.Adresse = a.AdressNrADR
        LEFT JOIN ADR_GruppenLink gl ON a.AdressNrADR = gl.AdressNrADR
        LEFT JOIN ADR_Gruppen g ON gl.GruppeADR = g.GruppeADR 
) src
pivot
( max(menge)
for tag IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[35])
) piv;
```

Answer (score 0):

The numeric column name is problematic.  Try including the table alias when referencing the numeric column names: as in table.1, table.2 instead of 1, 2

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sadly it doesnt work. I get an error, only works when i make dbo.ws_monatsreport.[1]